# MySQL - Join if no duplicate

Tags: mysql, join

I want to Join to table. the condition is I want to only join those rows which have only one row to match. eg.

books:

```
id | name   | price
1  | book1  | 19
2  | book2  | 19
3  | book3  | 30
```

price_offer:

```
id | offer  | price
 1 | offer1 | 19
 2 | offer2 | 30
```

so now if I do select query on these table:

```
SELECT * FROM price_offer
JOIN books ON price_offer.price = books.price
```

I only want to join book with id 3 as it have only one match with price_offer table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self join for books table to pick a book with only single match

```
select po.*, b1.*
from price_offer po
join books b1 on po.price = b1.price
join (
    select price,max(id) id
    from books
    group by price
    having count(*) = 1
)  b2 on b1.id = b2.id
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KWUB98453)

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

Sample data:

```
create table books(id int, name varchar(10), price int);
insert into books values
(1, 'book1', 19),
(2, 'book2', 19),
(3, 'book3', 30);

create table price_offer(id int, offer  varchar(10), price int);
insert into price_offer values
(1, 'offer1', 19),
(2, 'offer2', 30);
```

Query:

```
select max(b.id)
from price_offer p 
left join books b on b.price = p.price
where p.id is not null
group by b.price
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid nesting queries where you have to use self-joins, you can use window-functions of MySQL 8.0.11, which are exactly for cases like this